# Show that (Ω,A,P) is a probability space consisting entirely of sets independent in their entirety

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Let $ \mathcal{A}:=\{A \in \mathcal{F} \mid \mathbb{P}(A)=0 $ or $ \mathbb{P}(A)=1\} $.

Show that $ (\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}) $ is a probability space consisting entirely of sets independent in their entirety, i.e.

(a) $ \mathcal{A} $ is an $ \sigma $ algebra.

(b) For all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ and all $ A_{1}, \ldots, A_{n} \in \mathcal{A} $ with $ A_{i} \neq A_{j} $ for all $ i \neq j $, $ \mathbb{P}\left(A_{1} \cap \ldots \cap A_{n}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(A_{1}\right) \cdots \mathbb{P}\left(A_{n}\right) $ holds.

Attempt:

For a): (i) $ \emptyset, \Omega \in \mathcal{A} $, since $ P(\emptyset)=0 $ and $P(\Omega) = 1$.

(ii) Let be $ A \in \mathcal{A} $.

Case 1: Let $P(A) \in \{0,1\} $. Thus also $ \left(P(A)^{c}\right)^{c} \in \{0,1\} $ and $ A^{c} \in \mathcal{A} $.

Case 2: Let $ A \notin \{0,1\} $. Then $ A^{c} \in \{0,1\} $ holds, because otherwise $ A $ would not be contained in $ \mathcal{A} $. Thus $ A^{c}$ is in $\mathcal{A} $.

So $\mathcal{A} $ is closed concerning the complement.

iii) Suppose $A_k \in {\cal A}$, then $P(A_k) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $k$. If $P(A_k) = 1$ for any $k$ then $P (\cup_k A_k) \ge P(A_k) = 1$, otherwise $P(A_k) = 0$ for all $k$ and
$P(\cup_k A_k) \le \sum_k PA_k = 0$.

Does a) make sense like this?
But with b) I'm still unsure how to show it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof to (a) is correct.  And the proof to (b) is pretty much similar.

If any $A_i$ has probability $0$, then $P(A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) \leq P(A_i) = 0$, whence $P(A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) = 0$, the equality to be proven holds.  Otherwise, $P(A_1) = \cdots = P(A_n) = 1$, implying $P(A_1^c) = \cdots = P(A_n^c) = 0$, whence
\begin{align}
P(A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) = 1 - P((A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n)^c) = 1 - P(A_1^c \cup 
\cdots \cup A_n^c) \geq 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^n P(A_i^c) = 1,
\end{align}
hence $P(A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) = 1 = P(A_1) \cdots P(A_n)$. This completes the proof of (b).